# Site collection administrators in site setting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions, 2016

I am a member in site owner group, but I can't find Site collection administrators link in site setting!!

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue, and can it be solved within SharePoint? Thanks.

Comment: You need to be site collection admin to see the link. Owner are not admins.

Comment: What Gautam said. Would not be to good if any owner could access the site collection administrator setting and change those. Anarchy for everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is mentioned by `Waqsa` is correct, you should be `Site Collection Administrator` to can find the `Site collection administrators` option within the site setting page.

But based on your above comments, you still missing the link despite you have already signed in as a site collection administrator.

---

Actually, it's a strange behavior, but I suspect that **you are not in the `Site Setting` page of the top level site collection.**

[image]

It's logical, the Site collection administrators option is not shown in the **site setting of subsite** even you are using Site collection administrator :)

So Make sure that you are already in the `Site Setting` of **the root (Top level) site**, to can find the `Site Collection Administrator`

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is correct. There is difference between the `Site collection administrator Or Site collection owner` **vs** `Site Owner Groups`.

**Site collection administrator Or Site collection owner**: These are the user who owns the site collection and having ownership of it. I.e. Primary Site collection admin or Secondary Site collection admin. These guys received the alerts about the site collections i.e storage quota, not used etc. These owner controlled by Central admin or Pwoershell. You can also add extra site collection administrators which is controlled via Site setting page.

**Site Owner Group**
Site Owner groups is just a security group in SharePoint site collection with Full control on the site collection but not the owner of the Site collection or Primary or secondary Site collection Administrator. when we create a new site collection, 3 groups will automatically provisioned with "Sitename Members", "Sitename Owners" and "Sitename Visitor". This is just permission group not really admin / owner of the site collections.

If you make some body owner of the site collection then you have to make it Primary or Secondary admin from CA or powershell, if you want add additional site collection administrators then  add into the Site Collection Administrators permission group via site settings of site collection.

Read this heading ["Site Owners vs Site Collection administrators demystified"](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/site-owner-vs-site-collection-administrator)

Comment: Thank you, sounds right! I must be site collection admin but I logined as system account to the same site and still missing the link! WHY?

Comment: is the system account is site collection administrator? check from central amdmin.

Comment: Yes, it's the site collection!

Comment: are you on subsite level or site collection level? also logout from browser and re login.